# get nowTime as NSDate Object to compare to other dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to get the current time in a 24 hour format to compare to other nsdate objects I created from a string. In thid case I dont have a string time so i tried created one but I cant get it to work. This is my code:

```
 let now = NSDate()
   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dateString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(now, dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
    let currentTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    print(currentTime)
```

current time is nil, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all of the code in your question with just:

```
let currentTime = NSDate()
```

That's it. Use that `currentTime` to compare to your other `NSDate` objects.

There is no need for all of the date formatting and conversions.

Comment: but when i print current time it prints it in a different format and the time is not right either, it prints "2016-04-13 05:18:20 +0000" and it is 11:18 of april the 12 th

Comment: That's just the standard output when you log an `NSDate`. Don't worry about that, it's irrelevant. `currentTime` represents "now".

Comment: will it make any difference if I'm comparing it to a nsdate with a 24 hour format?

Comment: What do you mean by "an `NSDate` with a 24-hour format"? An `NSDate` represents a point in time. If you have two `NSDate` objects, you can simply compare them with the `compare:` function. Try it.

Comment: I'll try it, just curious though, when i print my other nsdate, it prints with a 24 hour format "2016-05-06 14:00:00 +0000"

Comment: You get that format when printing any `NSDate` object.

Comment: ok im getting confused here, when i print currentTime = NSdate()  i get "2016-04-13 05:18:20 +0000" and when i print my other nsdate object ""2016-05-06 14:00:00 +0000" i get a 24 hour format lol.

Comment: What time zone are you in?  UTC-6?  05:18:20 is a 24 hour format - it is currently 5:29 am UTC

Comment: @GamalielTellezOrtiz Those are both being printed in 24-hour time. Why do you think one is and one isn't?

Comment: You compare two same NSDate?

Comment: nope, Im at mountain time and it is 11:30 still the 12th, the currentTime = NSdate prints that is it is already the 13th " "2016-04-13 05:18:20 +0000". That is why I dont feel confident to just use nsdate() lol

Comment: Look at the output. It's printing your current time (11:30 PM MDT) in UTC time. Since you are 6 hours behind UTC, 11:30 PM MDT is the same time as 05:30 AM UTC the next day. It's the same moment in time, just logged with a different timezone.

Comment: So your local time is 2016-04-12 23:30:00 -0600 - This is the same as 2016-04-13 05:30:00 +0000

Comment: i see that, so it doesnt matter if i compare two nsdate with different time zone? lol

Comment: `NSDate` doesn't have timezones. A timezone is only relevant when converting the `NSDate` to a string for display. When you compare two `NSDate`, the timezone is irrelevant.